# Codeception won't build modules configured in global config

Tags: php, unit-testing, codeception

I have this in my `codeception.yml` in tests root folder config:

```
include:
  - codeception/backend
  - codeception/common
  - codeception/console

paths:
  log: codeception/_output

settings:
  colors: true

modules:
    enabled:
      - Db
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db1_test'
            user: 'root'
            password: 'qwerty'
            cleanup: true
```

Then this in mu `codeception/codeception.yml`:

```
namespace: tests\codeception\backend
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: .
    log: _output
    data: _data
    helpers: _support
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    suite_class: \PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
    log: true
config:
    # the entry script URL (without host info) for functional and acceptance tests
    # PLEASE ADJUST IT TO THE ACTUAL ENTRY SCRIPT URL
    test_entry_url: http://ds3/index-test.php
```

And then this in my `codeception/unit.suite.yml`:

```
class_name: UnitTester
modules:
    enabled:
      - Db
```

But I get the following error when I run `codecept build` from tests root folder:

```
[Codeception\Exception\ModuleConfigException]                     
  Db module is not configured!                                      

  Options: dsn, user, password are required                         
  Please, update the configuration and set all the required fields
```

If I remove `- Db` from `codeception/unit.suite.yml` the module just doesn't run at all. It seems like global config's `modules` section is ignored completely. It won't even affect anything if there is a typo in `Db` in global config. But I need to have only one config for Db for each suite and each application. What am I doing wrong? Documentation says it should be possible to declare modules globally.

Comment: Remove enabled section from codeception.yml

Comment: @Naktibalda, the same `Db module is not configured! ` error appears when doing `codecept build`. I have previously omitted one of the configs in the middle. Maybe it helps to notice something. I don't really understand what these namespaces and class and actor names options do. Documention doesn't cover any of these at all.

Comment: Put config section back.

Comment: @Naktibalda, you mean `codeception/unit.suite.yml`? What should I write there?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, to clarify:  This is my codecetion.yml file (different project from above, but tested for your scenario):

```
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    helpers: tests/_support
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: false
    memory_limit: 1024M
modules:

    config:
        DataHelper:
          db:
            host: 02corm.za.ds.xxxxxxx.com
            user: xxxxxxx
            password: yyyyyyy
            port: 3306
          env:
            stubDelay: 2
            otdWebhook: http://xxxxxx.com:9080/api/webhook/
            otdStubUrl: http://xxxxxx.com:9080/api/
```

and my api.suite.yml:

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser
        - REST
        - ApiHelper
        - DataHelper
        - CurlHelper
        - OtdHelper
        - Asserts
        - WooCommerceHelper
        - ResponseHelper
    config:
        PhpBrowser:
            url: http://dev.xxxx.co.za 
            curl:
              CURLOPT_TIMEOUT: 50000 # timeout in seconds
        REST:
            url: http://dev.xxxx.co.za 
            timeout: 90



env:
  mini:
    modules:
      config:
        PhpBrowser:
          url: http://xxxxxx.com:9080/api/
          curl:
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT: 50000 # timeout in seconds
        REST:
             url: http://xxxxxx.com:9080/api/

dcr-static:
      modules:
        config:
          PhpBrowser:
            url: http://x.x.x.x:10080/api
            curl:
              CURLOPT_TIMEOUT: 50000 # timeout in seconds
          REST:
               url: http://x.x.x.x:10080/api
          DataHelper:
            db:
              host: x.x.x.x
              user: xxxxx
              password: yyyy
              port: 3307
            env:
              stubDelay: 2
              otdWebhook: http://x.x.x.x:10080/api/webhook/otd
              otdStubUrl: http://x.x.x.x:10080/otd-stub/service
```

In the above setup, I have two environments:  mini and dcr-static.

- In 'mini' there was no DataHelper configs supplied, so it is using the configs from codecetion.yml file.
- In 'dcr-static' I supplied an alternative config for this environment, which gets used instead of the one given in the codecetion.yml file

Answer (score 1):

It should look like this:

```
class_name: UnitTester
    modules:
        enabled:
            - Db
        config:
            Db:
              dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name_here;port=3306'
              user: 'user_here'
              password: 'password_here'
              dump: ''
              populate: false
              cleanup: false
              reconnect: true
```

Comment: Which config is it? The question is why it doesn't work in the global config. The point is to have only one config containing database credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem just now and solved it by running suites one at a time. Codeception only failed to load the configuration properly if I tried to run all the suites at once.